# Proving that sng(x) is discontinuous at 0?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that the signum function is discontinuous at $x_0 = 0$.  The criterion for discontinuity is that if there is a sequence $(x_n) \subseteq A$ and $(x_n) \rightarrow c$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(c)$.

I am trying to find a sequence that converges to 0 but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(c)$.  The only thing I can think of is $(x_n)$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ then $(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ but $f(x_n)$ will always be greater than $0$ so $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(c)$.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct. - in particular, it converges to 1.

Comment: The discontinuity at $0$ is worse than just an "unfortunate choice" at $0$. Note that $f$ is constantly $+1$ on $(0,\infty)$ and constantly $-1$ on $(-\infty,0)$; this means $f(0-)\neq f(0+)$, so there is no way to "redefine" $f(0)$ to make $f$ continuous at $0$. In other words, the value *at* $0$ doesn't even matter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The justification isn't quite strong enough: After all, if we consider this $x_n$ with $g(x) = x$, it's still true that $g(x_n)$ is always greater than $0 = g(0)$.

To fill the gap, you'll need to use that $f(1/n)$ is actually a *constant* sequence.